# Breaking the python code when particular file is being opened

Tags: python, debugging

I want to run code under debugger and stop it when file being opened. I want to do that regardless of technique by which the file was opened. AFAIK there are two ways of opening file (if there are more then I want to stop code also on that case) and I want to stop the code when one of those are being executed:

```
with open(filename, "wb") as outFile:
```

or

```
object = open(file_name [, access_mode][, buffering])
```

is this possible under `pdb` or `ipdb` ?

PS: I do not know the line where file is being opened if I know I can set the breakpoint manually. Also I could `grep` for `open(` and set the breakpoint on found lines but if my code uses modules this might been problematic. Also if the file is opened another way not by `open` (I do not know if this is possible just guessing, maybe for appending etc.) this wouldn't work.

Comment: I think you can put `pdb` inside `with` block.

Comment: So you want to flag a particular file, and stop the debugger when this file is opened? See my answer!

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but it didn't get many views. Consider rewriting the title. Also, the "example" code is confusing.

Comment: But just to be sure, did I understand you properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd put a breakpoint in the open builtin function, but that is not possible. Instead, you can override it, and place the breakpoint there:

```
import __builtin__

def open(name, mode='', buffer=0):
    return __builtin__.open(name, mode, buffer) # place a BreakPoint here
```

Of course you'll be breaking at any file opening, not just the one you wanted.

So you can refine that a bit and place a conditional breakpoint:

```
import ipdb
import __builtin__

def open(name, mode='', buffer=0):
    if name == 'myfile.txt':
        ipdb.set_trace()  ######### Break Point ###########
    return __builtin__.open(name, mode, buffer)

f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
```

Run your python program with `python -m pdb prog.py`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know where the open call is, you need to patch the original `open` at the earliest possible point (e.g. the `__main__`-guard) like this:

```
 import __builtin__

 _old_open = open

 def my_open(*args, **kwargs):
     print "my_open"
     return _old_open(*args, **kwargs)

 setattr(__builtin__, 'open', my_open)

 print open(__file__, "rb").read()
```